# How to extend an existing method to handle a more specific type in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3

The `NSCoder` class has the `func encode(_ objv: Any?, forKey key: String)` method. I want to provide a custom implementation for objects which implement some protocol. It's definitely possible if I subclass `NSCoder`. But may I do this in an extension?

This doesn't work (the method never gets called):

```
extension NSCoder {

  func encode(_ objv: SomeProtocol?, forKey key: String) {
    // do my stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the type being passed in as `objv`

Comment: @Alexander normally it's `Any?`, in my method I want to take care of `SomeProtocol?`.

Comment: Yeah I get that, that's not what I asked. In your test case, in which you observed that your method doesn't get called, what type is the variable you're passing into the value of `objv`?

Comment: @Alexander sorry for missunderstanding. I passed a struct which inherits `SomeProtocol`.

Comment: Now what happens if you explicitly wrap that up into an Optional?

Comment: @Alexander I'm in a train, can't try right now. Do you think it would work if I specified a concrete struct's name? I'll try, but unfortunately that's not what I want to achieve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133380/discussion-between-alexander-and-artem-stepanenko).